# Mule foreach : Splitter returned no results

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I get a list of files on amazon S3 and iterate over the list of files and process one file at a time. The corresponding flow is as follows --

```
<flow name="process-from-s3" doc:name="process-from-s3"
    processingStrategy="synchronous">
    <poll doc:name="Poll" frequency="${s3-poll-interval}">
        <s3:list-objects config-ref="Amazon_S3" doc:name="Get List of files"
            accessKey="${s3-access-key}" secretKey="${s3-secret-key}"
            bucketName="${s3-read-bucket}" />
    </poll>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <foreach doc:name="For Each">
                <set-session-variable variableName="s3_file_name" value="#[payload.getKey()]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
                <logger message="From bucket ( ${s3-read-bucket} ), received the file #[s3_file_name]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
                <flow-ref name="process_s3_file" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
            </foreach>
    </choice>
</flow>
```

The flow works well, however it keeps on spitting the following log statements if there are no files found.

```
[03-06 21:52:05] WARN  Foreach$CollectionMapSplitter   
[[myapp].connector.polling.mule.default.receiver.01]: Splitter returned no results. 
If this is not expected, please check your split expression
```

How can I avoid this annoying log message. Should I wrap the foreach within a choice router that processes the foreach if there is atleast one element in the list. Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather set the log level for `org.mule.routing.Foreach$CollectionMapSplitter` to `ERROR` than configure any additional logic for this warning. See [Mule docs](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Configuring+Logging) for configuring logger/log4j if you need to.

Comment: Add the line `<logger name="org.mule.routing">
  <level value="error"/>
 </logger>` to your `log4j.xml`.